# C# over html doesn't generate the variables

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor

I'm trying to retrieve data in a `.cshtml` file.

The C# code is like this:

```
@functions{
    public void sendAuto()
    {
        string marca = marcaInput.Value;
        string modello = modelloInput.Value;
        int anno = annoInput.Value;
        int prezzo = prezzoInput.Value;
    }
}
```

While the values I'm trying to retrieve are in inputs like this:

```
<input id="marcaInput" name="marcaInput" 
       class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="" runat="server"/>
```

Somehow the variable `marcaInput` and the others are not found, am I missing some dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've forgot an @ symbol before your values

It should go like

```
<input id="marcaInput" name="@marca" class="form-control form-control-sm" ...
```

Also if you're not getting "marcaInput" values you should probably get them from a Model class you're passing to your view. It goes something like this:

```
@page
@using RazorPagesIntro.Pages
@model Index2Model
```

in your View header.

You can read more on that in the [official Razor Pages tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)